# Create Data Validation(DropDown) based on certain criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

All I want to do is display data in a data validation(DropDown) based on certain criteria. Is it really that difficult to display A8:A13 where E8:E13=Vehicle ???
I know im very new to excel, but this just seems like im being stupid!

I have this formula(Which is a name range), it displays the correct data, but ONLY based on the value from another cell:

```
=OFFSET('Fleet List'!$A$9,MATCH($A$8,'Fleet List'!$A$9:$A$13,0)-1,1,COUNTIF('Fleet List'!$E$9:$E$13,"Vehicle"),1)
```

Ive tried playing with INDEX and OFFSET, but not coming right, possibly because I dont understand how they fit together :( Im feeling real dumb today and about to start punching my screen...

This is how my table looks:

```
|Fleet No.|Reg No.|Vehicle Type|

    A1       ABC1     Vehicle
    A2       ABC2     Vehicle
    B1       XYZ1     Trailer
```

Now all I want to do is display a list for Fleet No. from Sheet2 Where Vehicle Type = Vehicle, in Cell A1 in Sheet1.

It cant be that complicated in Excel can it ?

You may laugh at me, but I just really need some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: From what I can make out, is that you want to create a Dependent Drop Down List. I could write a step by step guide but as there is so many examples online, I would be repeating what is already out there and it can get fairly complex. There are online videos that give good step by step instruction which I found helpful when I first encountered this problem. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Thom, I will do some research on Dependant Drop Down Lists. I will revert back to you, thanks for the info!

Comment: @Thom I think the difference in this case is that the list isn't explicitly written out anywhere on the worksheet but would rather have to be filtered from two columns, one with a fleet number and then second with it's corresponding vehicle type. A dependent drop down list would still require separate columns of fleet numbers for each vehicle type.

Comment: It seems dependant drop down lists are for displaying a list, based on another selection. THis isnt what I want. I just want to select the Fleet No's(From Column A) where Vehicle Type(from Column C) = "Vehicle". Can this not simply be done in a formula in a name range ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, just making use of a formula, which is what I was wanting to do:

```
=OFFSET(FleetNoRange[Fleet No.],MATCH("Vehicle",'Fleet List'!$E$9:$E$13,0)-1,0,COUNTIF('Fleet List'!$E$9:$E$13,"Vehicle"),1)
```

Im still sure there is an easier way - But this works, and I dont have time to keep looking, otherwise I might be minus a screen or laptop soon.

Thanks for the replies nevertheless guys.

Cheers!